# Find highest recurring duplicates in a javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array with several names like : 
`[mike,bob,john,john,rick,bob]`
Can someone please tell me how is the most efficient way to find which name has been repeated the most?

Comment: You should edit your question to show what you've done so far, and where you're having trouble.

Comment: There are any number of existing questions about counting duplicates in an array. Surely you can adapt the code from [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26237031/check-an-array-for-duplicate-values-get-value-and-get-count?noredirect=1&lq=1) or [another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12749200/how-to-count-array-elements-by-each-element-in-javascript) of them? Have a look at the "Related" questions listed on the bottom-right of this page.

Answer (score 0):

Generate an object with count using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method, later sort the property name array(get using [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) method) based on the count using [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Sort) method and finally get the first element.

```js
var arr = ['mike', 'bob', 'john', 'john', 'rick', 'bob'];

// generate an object which holds the count
var obj = arr.reduce(function(o, v) {
  // define the property if not defined
  o[v] = o[v] || 0;
  // increment the count
  o[v]++;
  // return the object reference
  return o;
  // set initial value as an empty object
}, {});

// sort based on the count, descending order
// and get first
console.log(
  Object.keys(obj).sort(function(a, b) {
    return obj[b] - obj[a];
  })[0]
)

// or using reduce, reduce into a single value 
// which holds the highest value
console.log(
  Object.keys(obj).reduce(function(a, b) {
    return obj[b] > obj[a] ? b : a;
  })
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard solution to find duplicates (in O(n) time) is to walk linearly through the list and add each item to a set. Each time, before doing so, check if it is already in the set. If it is, you've found a duplicate.

```
names = [ 'mike', 'bob', 'john', 'john', 'rick', 'bob'];

seen = new Set();

names.forEach(function(item, index, array) {
    if (seen.has(item)) {
        console.log(item + " is a duplicate");
    } else {
        seen.add(item);
    }
});
```

Alternately, you can sort in O(n log(n)) time, and save the extra space that was used above, by sorting and checking pair-wise as you iterate over the array:

```
names = [ 'mike', 'bob', 'john', 'john', 'rick', 'bob'];

names.sort().forEach(function(item, index, array) {
    if ((index > 0) && (array[index - 1] == item)) {
        console.log(item + " is a duplicate");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could find with the help of `map` as follows

```js
   function findDuplicates() {
     var name, names = ['mike', 'bob', 'john', 'john', 'rick', 'bob'];
     var map = new Map();
     var max = 1;
     var maxRecurringString = "";
        for(name of names) {
    
           if(map.get(name) === undefined) {
              map.set(name, 1);
           } else {
              var count = map.get(name);
              count = count+1;
              map.set(name, count);
                  if(max < count) {
                     max = count;
                     maxRecurringString = name;
                  }
            }
     }
    console.log("Maximum recurring string is ", maxRecurringString, ". Max number of times :" + max);
  }
findDuplicates();
```

This snippet prints the first string which appears maximum number of times. Say for example in the above example `bob` and `john` has appeared twice. If you want all the strings to be printed which has appeared maximum number of times you can iterate for the map whose count is the `max` count to print all the strings.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function findDup(arr){
   var obj={};
   for(var i of arr){
      if(obj[i]==1){
        console.log(i);
      }
     obj[i]=1;
   }
 }
 findDup([ 'mike', 'bob', 'john', 'john', 'rick', 'bob']);
```

Comment: how to add snippet like you have adde above?

Comment: It's very neat.. how to make such snippet while answering?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the most efficient way to do this, talking about performance, the best way is to loop over the array only once.

[Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), [Array#sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Sort), [Array#forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) will loop over the entire array, so if you're concerned about performance *(specially working with considerable amount of data)*, avoiding those is the best practice

```js
var findHighestRecurring = function(arr) {
    arr.sort();

    var i        = arr.length;
    var max      = { item:"", count: 0 };
    var last     = { item:"", count: 0 };
    var validate = function() {
        if (last.count > max.count) {
            max.item  = last.item;
            max.count = last.count;
        }
    }

    while (i--) {
        var curr = arr[i];

        if (last.item !== curr) {
            validate();
            
            last.item  = curr;
            last.count = 0;
        }
        
        last.count++;
    }

    validate();

    return max;
}

var sample = ["mike","bob","john","bob","john","rick","bob"];
var result = findHighestRecurring(sample);

console.log(result);
```